# not getting update notification for app updated on play store?

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

My app updated and published in the play store. And when I search for the app it shows UPDATE button also. In MYAPPS menu in play store app also listing my app in update list.

My problem is:

=> it is not giving me any update notification on my app in notification bar.

=> I have selected auto update over WIFI. and checked auto-update for the app. (these  settings were already set same)

I did all the things as listed in the article : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

it says 24 hour will take to list update in play store. In my case it got listed within 3 hours, but so far it hast reached 24 hr, is that 24 hour is necessary to get notified where it already listed as update.

please tell me if anything more I have to do.

Comment: try just open play store app and wait and close. you will get update notification. This is because notification service might not running frequently but when you open app, it will run and checked updates notifications.

Comment: the device searches for updates of application likely at every boot, try to reboot and it might show up.........guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having an update available doesnt mean instant notification.
If user manually searches for it (like you did) they'll find it and can choose to update at that time.
Otherwise notification will take as long as the phone takes to automatically search for application updates.

Theres no further actions you for you to take besides uploading the update. Users will eventually be notified, sooner or later.

Comment: yes.. got updated (auto updated over WIFI) after 24 hours.no reboot or anything else!

Comment: People implement their own update api for controling things like soft & hard update. just call the api on your splash and show the popup accordingly.

Comment: I have not received update notification even after more than 24 hours. what to do?