# Not receiving update notification for my android app on play store

Tags: android, google-play

I had published my first Android App. on Play Store. Then, I updated it again for fixing some bugs. My app is updated successfully on google play but I am not receiving the update notification on the play store.

Also, when I search my app in the play store after updating it, some devices show the option for "open" or some shows the option for "update".

My concern is, how will my users get to know about the new update and why are users not getting any update notification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not getting update notification for app updated on play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709054/not-getting-update-notification-for-app-updated-on-play-store)

Comment: So, should I wait for 24 hours after updating the App.

Comment: You need to wait a few minutes to hours to get notified.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39657445/4629101) page and you'll find your answer.

Comment: I have not received update notification even after more than 24 hours. what to do?